# When are complex numbers insufficient?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, complex-analysis, nonstandard-analysis

Rationals can't solve $x^2=2$, and reals can't solve $x^2=-1$. Is there any problem that cannot be solved by complex numbers but can be solved by non-standard numbers?

Every polynomial with coefficients in $C$ can be solved by numbers in $C$, can every equation* be solved by numbers in $C$?

*(that can not be simplified to $1=0$)

Comment: Your first Q's A depends on how you define a number since you already know C. Your 2nd Q: yes, because C is a field and if manipulations are also defined in this field.

Comment: Certainly not every equation has a solution in $\mathbb{C}$.  As a trivial example, $1=2$, or to make it look more like an equation in a variable, $z+1-z=2$.  As a less trivial example, consider $z \bar{z} = -1$.

Comment: The equation $e^z=0$ cannot be "simplified" to $1=0$, but it doesn't have any solutions in $\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: Why would you use the tag [nonstandard-analysis]?

Comment: @ZevChonoles The equation $e^z=0$ can be "simplified" by multiplication with $e^{-z}$. Guess what you get...

Comment: @Thomas: That's true, but as long as we're playing that game, the statement that an equation $f(z)=0$ can't be solved is then *equivalent* to the statement that $1=0$, since $f$ has no zeros and is therefore invertible. Wouldn't you agree that there is at least content in the statement that there is no solution to $e^z=0$?

Comment: @ZevChonoles Good point, you are right.

Comment: @ZevChonoles: I think that statement is exactly what Holowitz was looking for.

Answer (score 6):

As $\mathbb{C}$ is commutative, non-commutative problems cannot be solved in it.

E.g. $A \cdot B - B \cdot A = I.$

Equations like this are central to Quantum Mechanics and Lie Algebras.

However, matrices usually are non-commutative, so matrices over $\mathbb{C}$ or $\mathbb{R}$ are able to solve those equations. As can quaternions among others.

EDIT: You say that you are looking for *non-standard numbers*. May I suggest to have a look at **Quaternions**? They are the logical next step after $\mathbb{C}$. The [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternions) entry might be a good starting point. Quaternions are a bit out of fashion, but theoretically and historically they are important.

Comment: This is precisely 0=I

Comment: @hyperion It's only 0=I when AB = BA. When something is *non-commutative*, one cannot assume that AB = BA anymore.

Answer (score 4):

The problem, "find a number strictly greater than zero but strictly less than every number $1/n$ with $n=1,2,3,\dots$" cannot be solved in the complex numbers, but can be solved in the non-standard numbers.

Comment: I don't quite get this example, since there is no well-ordering of the complex numbers.

Comment: Perhaps I should have put it this way: the problem can't be solved in the reals, and it doesn't help any to extend to the complex numbers, but it can be solved in the non-standard numbers. Or this way: find a number whose *modulus* is strictly greater than zero but....

Answer (score 0):

I would like to respond to the question "Is there any problem that cannot be solved by complex numbers but can be solved by non-standard numbers?"  Since one of the tags is "nonstandard analysis", I will interpret this as applying the the nonstandard numbers in that theory, namely the hyperreals.  Back to the question: one important problem that the hyperreals allow one to solve, is relating the derivative of a function to ratios of infinitesimals, as it was done by Leibniz, a co-founder of infinitesimal calculus.